# Spring MVC не обрабатывает запрос

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Есть контроллер, отлично обрабатывает все GET запросы, но почему-то POST не ловит.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/addAccount", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public void addAccount() {
        System.out.println("Account on the top");
    }
```

А это форма отправляющая POST запрос:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post">

                <label>
                    Сумма: <input type="number" name="sum">
                </label>
                <br> <br>

                <label>
                    Категория:
                    <select name="category">
                        <option value="university">Университет</option>
                        <option value="job">Работа</option>
                        <option value="shop">Магазин</option>
                        <option value="cafe">Кафе</option>
                        <option value="entertainment">Развлечения</option>
                        <option value="other">Другое</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <label>Комментарий:
                    <br> <br>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Внести">

            </form>
```

При нажатии на submit получаю:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

А просто при переходе по адресу (на который меня же кинула форма) запрос корректно обрабатывается.

Логи спринга:

```
10-Mar-2016 10:29:58.345 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/account/addAccount] onto handler 'mainController'
10-Mar-2016 10:29:58.345 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/account/addAccount.*] onto handler 'mainController'
10-Mar-2016 10:29:58.345 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/account/addAccount/] onto handler 'mainController'
```

P.S. 
Ради эксперимента я создал ещё 2 метода:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("123");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("1234");
    }
```

Так вот, проверил через postman, ситуация повторилась, GET ловит, а POST нет.

Comment: Уверены, что у вас всё корректно побилдилось и вы не используете какой-то старый код? Можете включайте логи и смотрите куда замапился ваш метод и какие HTTP методы он обрабатывает.

Comment: Спринг пишет лог WARNING
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: build прошёл нормально

Comment: Логи при старте, если включить дебаг, то спринг выдаст как он замапил ваш контроллер и его методы, на какие URL и HTTP методы. А чистили перед билдом?

Comment: клин только что сделал, сейчас посмотрю в дебаге

Comment: Достаточно просто запустить в ide приложение в дебаг-моде, верно?

Comment: Я обновил главный пост и добавил в него логи

Comment: Добавил ещё 2 контроллера, очень странное поведение

Comment: Проблему решил, оформил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в Spring Security, который автоматически подключает защиту от атаки типа `csrf` (межсайтовая подделка запроса), дело в том, что для чтобы запрос прошёл он должен нести в себе некий `csrf.token`, так вот, я отправлял форму на сервер в тэгах  , и не передавал никакой токен вместе с формой. А токен передать необходимо.

Два решения этой проблемы:

1. Использовать `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>` и передавать не `<form>`, а `<form:form>`, тогда спринг сам подставит строчку с токеном в html страницу (это видно при просмотре исходного кода страницы).
2. Руками добавить эту строку, вот она: `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />`
3. Отключение csrf защиты в Spring Security, как это сделать, лучше читать в документации, т.к. версии спринга меняются. (Но, мне кажется этот способ неудачным решением проблемы)

Comment: а если добавить в конфиг секьюрити 

     http
                .csrf().disable()

Comment: Сначала я так и сделал, отключил в конфиге Spring-Security защиту csrf и всё заработало. Но, мне кажется, что отключение защиты не самое лучшее решение, не так ли? :)

Comment: Хотя я дополню свой ответ, вдруг кому-то пригодится и такой подход.

Comment: да я не знаю. делал учебный проект соц сети и я там отключал. Не знаю очень это плохо или нет)

Comment: Я работаю в компании занимающийся информационной безопасностью и скажу вам, что да - плохо)

Comment: а если вам надо будет послать запрос например с андроида?

Comment: С андройдом не работал, поэтому не могу ответить

Comment: Во всяком случае всегда можно отключить эту защиту и написать свою реализацию если необходимо

Comment: если хотите - добавляйтесь в скайп :) richirichi197